# Что показывает график installs в google play?

Tags: google-play

Понятно что кол-во загрузок. Но за какой период?

Например, написано `10,000,000 - 50,000,000` - это загрузок в день, неделю, месяц или нижняя-верхняя планка графика?

Answer (score 1):

Точную статистику можно видеть только в консоле разработчика, "10,000,000 - 50,000,000" - это всего лишь диапазон, нижняя граница которого показывает, что за все время было больше скачиваний, чем она, хотя на самом деле активных установок(на текущий момент) может быть очень мало.